Extracting First Minute from Recording
I am wondering if there is a way of extracting the first minute of a 5-minute audio recording in Raven pro software that allows me to maintain the BirdNET (Learning Detector) Selection Table entries for the aforementioned extracted times?
Thank you so much for your time and support :)

It might help to understand what your larger goal is so we can make additional more specific suggestions beyond @Dominik's very helpful answer!

In case you are only interested in the BirdNet results: You could use your favorite programming language and extract the section of interest from the txt file aka selection table. Iteratively as well, if it should be done for several files.
Additionally, you could well use R (or Python) to clip the first minute of all your sound files. Either way, I think it is worthwhile to treat the selection tables and sound files separately and use the tools of your liking.
